# What options exist to monitor reputation by "group" of users on a Stack Overflow Enterprise instance?

Tags: support, reputation, so-enterprise

I'm trying to figure out the best way to monitor/query/aggregate/analyse group reputation in a **Enterprise Stack Overflow instance**. These groups could be defined by email domain (by sub-company), for example.

The idea is getting info about how different groups/companies are performing on our private SO Enterprise instance.

Is there some specific feature for this? Should I rely on API directly?

Comment: Do you have something like [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) on your SO Enterprise instance?

Comment: I don't have the Enterprise instance running. I just evaluating our possibilities. SEDE looks like a very interesting tool. Is this tool part of some product?

Comment: well, it is seeded with data every week from the production databases of all SE sites in the network, including Stack Overflow. As it acts as a front-end on SQL Server you run rather complex sql queries to feed any curiosity. I'm not sure if SE enterprise users have some kind of similar access to their database. It needs either a dev or someone from pre-sales to confirm. SEDE it self is opensource but hosted by SE on their servers.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will check on that tool. I assume that there is not a specific feature in SO for my porpouses. If want something like a dashboard with company associated reputation I should develop it via API.

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Ok, it's just my first post man :) I'm sorry about that.

Comment: I've asked someone from SE to have a look at this request as well.

Comment: Hiya, @AndrésGuerrero :D We've pointed our Enterprise team at this. As a note, you can usually reach out through your Admin (assuming you aren't one) to our Customer Success Team with this sort of question and they'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After speaking with some of my coworkers, here's what I was able to find out for you:

Right now, we don't have anything that can do what you're trying to do outside of using the Enterprise API to get the results and mapping groups on your end. We do have API enhancements and existing features like User Groups, which will enable aspects of this in-product in the future.

I can't quite tell if you already have an Enterprise instance or if you're looking into it. If you're looking to consider it, our team would be happy to share more details, as well as demo current and upcoming features. You can [learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise/get-started). If you're already running an Enterprise instance, you should be able to reach out through your admin to get more information about this.